# How to create expiration date logic for a link shared via email

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I am sending a transaction ID as a link via email, using this link anyone can search for the details of transaction happened in my system. I would like to enforce expiry time for the link, say for 1 month link should work and post 1 month, link should expire.

I am using nodejs for implementing my software. I would like to send only transaction ID as the parameter for creating the link.

I planned to combine Transaction ID and expiry_timestamp and encode/encrypt and send the encoded/encrypted data as the parameter in the URL. Later when link is clicked and request is received to server, I should be able to retrieve the expiry_timestamp and compare it with current data and decide to proceed or no. Here if Iam sending timestamp in plaintext, user may change the timestamp and request, so I am planning to encode or encrypt it.

Please suggest some cryptographic techniques for implementing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way.

1. Create another column name something like `token`
2. Store expiry date and time on another column as you are already doing this.
3. Pass token as a query string that has been stored in DB rather than the timestamp.
4. when user click on the link you can check either validate or not using token (query string)

You can use this( https://www.npmjs.com/package/rand-token)  package to generate tokens.